# Ruby on Rails accessing back enum type in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following were my `product` model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

enum status: {
        disable: 0,
        enable: 1
    }

end
```

In my controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
private
        def set_product
            @product = Product.friendly.find(params[:id])
            if(@product.status != "disable"){
                @products
            } else {
                redirect_to root_path
            }
        end
end
```

Here `@product.status` returning either `disable` or `enable`, how can I use condition to check the product status? the above `@product.status != "disable"` is not working. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

When you have defined the enum then that will create some methods directly connect with the enum.

like disable?, enable?

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
private
  def set_product
    @product = Product.friendly.find(params[:id])
    if @product.disable?
      @products
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's because you @porduct's status is nil, maybe you need a migration to set a default status value to 0.

```
class SetProductStatusToZero < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :products, :status, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

It won't change anything to the already created records. To do that you would have to create a rake task or just go in the rails console and update all the records.